# Can't display the selection field in open erp

Tags: odoo

Here is the field information but it doesn't displayed in the web page

```
'type': fields.selection([('country','Country'),('state','State')],'Type'),
```

In my view the field is

```
<field name="type"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite see anything wrong with your code. There might be something else that's causing your problem. However you can try alter your code a bit:
Declare the selection as a global variable outside the class:

```
choice = (('country','Country'),('state','State'))
```

Then in your class:

```
'type_': fields.selection(choice,string='Type'),
```

Your xml is ok, but you can try adding the widget="selection":

```
<field name="type_" widget="selection"/>
```

Note that I renamed your field to **type_**, *type* might be reserved.